# What's the type of my Ubuntu kernel?

Tags: ubuntu, kernel

Four commands on my pc:

```
$ dpkg -l |grep linux-image
Linux kernel image for version 3.4.0 on 32 bit x86 SM
```

It means my Ubuntu kernel is 32 bits?

```
$ uname -a
Linux ny 3.4.0-030400-generic #201205210521 SMP Mon May 21 09:22:02 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ file /bin/ls
/bin/ls: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0x37cdd635587f519989044055623abff939002027, stripped

$ file /sbin/init
/sbin/init: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0x7aa29ded613e503fb09fb75d94026f3256f01e7a, stripped
```

up 3 commands mean my kernel is 64 bits?

My question: What is my kernel, 32 bits or 64 bits? Thanks.

Comment: I think you want http://www.serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

The `x86_64` indicates that it is a **64-bit** architecture (as an extension to the 32-bit x86 architecture - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64 for some additional details as to the history, etc.)